# Showing the existence of sub fields of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

For each divisor $m$ of $n$, $GF(p^n)$ has a unique sub field of order $p^m$ .

The proof of this theorem in Gallian goes like this :

Suppose that $m$ divides $n$. Then, since :

$(p^n-1) = (p^m-1)(p^{n-m})+p^{n-2m})+\cdots+p^{m}+1)$

Hence : $p^m-1$ divides $p^n-1 \implies p^n-1=(p^m-1)t$ for some $t$.

Let $K=\{ x \in GF(p^n)~~|~~x^{p^m}=x\}$

it can be now shown that $K$ is a sub field of $GF(p^n)$, we have $|K| \leq p^m$.

Let $\langle a \rangle=GF(p^n)^*$. Then $|a^t| = p^m-1$

> Since, $(a^t) p^{m-1} =1 \implies a^t \in K$

Hence, $K$ is a sub field of $GF(p^n)$ of order $p^m$.

I am not able to understand how $(a^t) p^{m-1} =1$. And how does that ensure that $a^t \in K$? Please give me some hints.

Thank you for your help..

Comment: It looks like a typo, i.e. $(a^t)p^{m-1}$ should read $(a^t)^{p^{m-1}}$.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks :)

Comment: More like $(a^t)^{p^m-1}$.

Comment: Yep... ${}{}{}{}$